# vb.net DataGridView - Replace Shortcut Key with typed character

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, keyboard-shortcuts

I have the problem that the DataGridView has obviously a shortcut key for <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> which seems to select the row.

What I would like to have is that pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> simply adds a space character to the current cursor position within the current cell (like for example in notepad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out a way which works well for me.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tb9t9a2t.aspx this shortcut key is just applied when `RowHeaderSelect` or `ColumnHeaderSelect` is used as `SelectionMode` - so i just changed it to `CellSelect`

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution, based on your idea of altering selection mode:

```
private void dataGridView_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
}

private void dataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;
}
```