# override DataGridView Shift+Space

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

In a DataGridView, pressing SHIFT and SPACE will by default select the entire row. The only solution I've found (referenced at [vb.net DataGridView - Replace Shortcut Key with typed character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339351/vb-net-datagridview-replace-shortcut-key-with-typed-character)) is to turn off the row select feature. While that works, it's not ideal, because I would still like to be able to select the whole row using the row selector (for example, to delete the row), and by changing the `SelectionMode` property to anything other than `RowHeaderSelect` I lose that ability. Is there a way to trap just the SHIFT+SPACE combination and replace it with a simple SPACE? It seems like none of the key events even recognize that keystroke when the control's `MutiSelect` property is set to `True` and the `SelectionMode` property is set to `RowHeaderSelect`, so I can't use those.

ETA: I thought maybe turning off `MultiSelect` and changing the selection mode to `CellSelect`, then adding an event handler for the `RowHeaderMouseClick` event would work...nope.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I figured out how to accomplish this was to inherit from DataGridView and override the ProcessCmdKey method. Then you can intercept the Shift+Space and just send on Space. Just add this class to your project and switch all of your DataGridViews to MyDataGridViews. My solution draws inspiration from this [DataGridView keydown event not working in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284370/datagridview-keydown-event-not-working-in-c-sharp) SO question (that also explains why Zaggler's solution doesn't work) and this [SendKeys in ProcessCmdKey: change Shift-Space to just a Space](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/435350-sendkeys-processcmdkey-change-shift-space-just-space) Bytes.com post. Sorry, but it's in C#.

```
class MyDataGridView : System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
{
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == (System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Space | System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift))
        {
            // DataGridView is dumb and will select a row when the user types Shift+Space 
            // if you have the DGV set so that you can click a row header to select a row (for example, to delete the row)
            // this method will intercept Shift+Space and just send on Space so that the DGV properly handles this. 
            // For example, if I type "ME TYPING IN ALL CAPS" it ends up looking like "METYPINGINALLCAPS".
            // Or if I type "Note: I have some OS thing to talk about" it looks like "Note:Ihave some OSthing to talk about"

            byte[] keyStates = new byte[255];
            UnsafeNativeMethods.GetKeyboardState(keyStates);
            byte shiftKeyState = keyStates[16];
            keyStates[16] = 0; // turn off the shift key
            UnsafeNativeMethods.SetKeyboardState(keyStates);

            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(" ");

            keyStates[16] = shiftKeyState; // turn the shift key back on
            UnsafeNativeMethods.SetKeyboardState(keyStates);
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

    [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    internal static class UnsafeNativeMethods
    {

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int GetKeyboardState(byte[] keystate);


        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int SetKeyboardState(byte[] keystate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution:

```
private void dataGridView_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
}

private void dataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here this works fine for me....

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown
    'Lets see what keys we have down shall we?'
    If My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown And e.KeyCode = Keys.Space Then
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Here's another way..

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown
    'Lets see what keys we have down shall we?'
    If My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown And e.KeyCode = Keys.Space Then
        'SendKeys.Send(Keys.Space)
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Just experiment with them and I hope something works out for you?

Comment: For some reason that KeyDown event isn't ever firing.

Comment: Have you set a break point on the sub to see if it is hitting it? Also make sure that your object name is correct for the handler...

Comment: Yup, breakpoint set, and I used the IDE to create the stub, so I know it's pointing at the right control and the right event. Just thought of something...This form is an MDI child, and its parent form overrides the `ProcessCmdKey` function, but at the end the function returns control to `MyBase.ProcessCmdKey`. That should allow other key-based events to fire, right?